# Creating a function to retrieve information from SQL

Tags: php, sql, function, func

I've searched the site for an answer but couldn't find any answer for my specific problem that worked.
I have two files, the first one is my index.php of-course, the second is my functions.php file, which obviously contains the functions, I made this function:

function sql_get($lang, $tabler, $rower){

```
if ($lang == "heb") { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = 0",
        mysql_real_escape_string($tabler));
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['$rower'];
}

else if ($lang == "rus") { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = 0",
        mysql_real_escape_string($tabler));
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['$rower'];
}
```

this code supposed to get an information about the language (from a get, it gets it, it's all fine with that), the sql table and the specific row from this table where the id is 0.

and return the information from the row inserted.

My warnings and errors when the language is "heb":

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home/elenbyin/public_html/elenby.co.il/vadim/functions.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/elenbyin/public_html/elenby.co.il/vadim/functions.php on line 17
```

and when the language is "rus":

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home/elenbyin/public_html/elenby.co.il/vadim/functions.php on line 23
```

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/elenbyin/public_html/elenby.co.il/vadim/functions.php on line 24

the function call in the index.php file looks like that:

I will be thankful for the people who will try to help and especially for those who will help me.

Thanks A lot!

Comment: **Rule 1**: you don't use [`mysql_`](http://php.net/mysql) functions -- they're deprecated. You can use [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Did you notice that you're doing the exact same thing inside the `if` and the `else` clauses ?

Comment: yeah i have noticed that, it'll be changed after i will get it to work that way

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you haven't connected to the database inside your function. If you've opened your database somewhere then you can get away with this with `mysql`, but you shouldn't.

Secondly, you're passing your variable as a second parameter to `mysql_query()`, but `mysql_query()` expects the query to be complete as the first parameter, and the second parameter should be the connection resource tht connects to the database, which you haven't got.

From the structure of the query it looks like you intend to use `sprintf()` to create it.

This should create the query for you, assuming you have opend a databse connection:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = 0",
    mysql_real_escape_string($tabler)); 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note: `mysql` is deprecated. You shouldn't use it. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. You'll need to be more rigorous about passing in your database connecions if you use `mysqli`.

Comment: If I may ask, why the sprintf?

Comment: The format of the OP's original query contained a `printf()` placeholder (`%s`), so I used `sprintf()` to create the query. There are plenty of other ways to do this, but `sprintf()` is a convenient way to create a query with a number of parameters that require escaping or other preprocessing. In this case it's really overkill.

Comment: no matter what my code is, it's stays the same error:
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/elenbyin/public_html/elenby.co.il/vadim/tryout.php on line 14

Comment: @LiorElenby This is now a different error from those you posted above. Your query is failing, probably because you haven't opened a connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As Amal suggested - better not use mysql_* functions cause not only they're deprecated but also vulnerable to sql-injection.

That said, in order to fix your code you should do:

```
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($tabler);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = 0";
$link=mysql_connect('host','user','pass');
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
...
```

as the second (and optional) parameter of mysql_query should be a [*resource*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - not a string!

Comment: I dont think the "select * from $table where id=0",mysql_real_escape_string(tabler) is wrong. :http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @koko check out the function's signature (from the link posted): `resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )` second (optional) parameter should be a resource, not a string. You can Google for more examples if you don't trust the one I wrote in the answer ;)